# Need to pass range of values to prepared statement

Tags: java

I need to pass range of values to prepared statement.

For eg.

505 is total count

need to divide it by 100

so the ranges will be like 1 to 100 ,101 to 200...501 to 505.

I have a code to implement this. But that is complex way of doing this.
Here I've attached the code. Is there any other easy way to do this?

```
upperValue = maxRowSize;
quotient = rowCount / maxRowSize;
rem = rowCount % maxRowSize;
if (rem == 0) {
    loopcount = quotient;
    finalValue = 0;
} else {
    loopcount = quotient + 1;
    finalValue = rem;
}
lowerValue = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < loopcount; i++) {
    if (finalValue != 0 && i == loopcount - 1) {
        upperValue = (lowerValue - 1) + finalValue;
    }
    resultSet = executeQuery(connection, query, lowerValue, upperValue);
```

Comment: Unless this code does not work, this is a better fit for a code review site.

Comment: does it really Java question?

Answer (score 1):

I think using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` in your (mysql) query would be a better choice.

Check this [link](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/451.cfm) for more details.